# How to traverse long linear file paths (only one child directories per parent) via hdfs command line?

Tags: hadoop, command-line

I have many paths in my HDFS which have long linear paths.
E.g.,:

```
/user/abc/a/b/c/d/x.txt
```

Here, after `/user/abc/a` (including a), all the directories have only one child directory. In such scenarios, I want to check the contents of `x.txt`, but I don't know the path till `x.txt`. I only know that it is present inside `/user/abc/a...`. In order to reach `x.txt`, currently, I run following commands:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/a 
hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/a/b
hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/a/b/c
hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/a/b/c/d
hadoop fs -cat /user/abc/a/b/c/d/x.txt
```

Instead, is there any way, by which with only one command, I'll be able to reach `x.txt` (Since there are no branches in the directory structure after `/user/abc/a`). Something like:

```
hadoop fs -<cmd> /user/abc/a
```

that will give us `/user/abc/a/b/c/d/x.txt` directly instead of `/user/abc/a/b`?

Also, if we have a linear path leading to a non-linear structure, it should lead me to the beginning of the non-linear structure. Hence if `/user/abc/a/b/c/d/` contains a directory `e` and a file `x.txt`, the output should be:

```
/user/abc/a/b/c/d/e
/user/abc/a/b/c/d/x.txt
```

Note that unlike `-R` switch (as mentioned in the first comment by @pjames), the recursion should stop as soon as the linearity ends in the path.

Comment: Have you tried `hadoop fs -ls -R ${PATH}`?

Comment: @pjames Yes, this is perfect in the cases where my linear path ends in a single file (The example given in my description). But after a long linear path, if I have a directory that contains multiple paths again, in which case I want only the path till that splitting directory, and not the recursive list of all the paths.

Nevertheless, -R will be helpful in such cases (if total number of leaf nodes in such a structure is less than 20). 

I'll update the question description as per the new information I got from you (-R switch). Thanks :)